# How to document teaching experiences?

Tags: teaching, professorship, recruiting

When applying for a senior academic position, teaching experiences play a critical role in the application. We list the corses we used to teach but when assuming the position, we need to deliver some official documents to the human resources?

1. What should be this document? a letter from the last university listing the courses or a detailed set of documents for each course/semester including evaluations?
2. Who should issue this document/letter? VP for Academics, Dean or Department Head?
3. Is it needed to get similar documents of teaching experiences from previous universities? or the last university is enough?

I am asking this question for the case of a full professor coming from Asia to Europe or North America.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to demonstrate excellent undergraduate and graduate teaching capabilities in academic position applications?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26416/how-to-demonstrate-excellent-undergraduate-and-graduate-teaching-capabilities-in)

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I do not think this is a duplicate. The linked question is about supplying evidence of excellence (which is quite subjective). This question is asking about evidence of actually teaching a subject (which should be quite objective).

Comment: @earthling I can not understand the difference between those objective and subjective terms. Could please explain them more?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent How do you prove you were an excellent teacher? You may think the teacher was great and I may think the same teacher on the same day was terrible. It is subjective (open to our interpretations). However, did the teacher actually teach that class? She was either there or she was not. If you and I were both in a position to know the truth (we were in class that day) we would never have different answers to the question "Was the teacher there that day." It is the difference between opinion and fact. The teacher was great (opinion). The teacher did teach the subject (fact).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think applicants in the US are ever required to prove that they taught particular courses on particular dates, so no system like official academic transcripts certified by the university has arisen. However, if there were some doubt that courses listed on a CV were not taught, it would be a simple matter of contacting the department to verify.